# Add images to laravel mix manifest without calling version()

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using [laravel mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix), and in production, I call `.version(["public/images"])` so my images are added to the manifest and get the cache buster hash added. In development, I still want my images added to the manifest, but I don't want to call `.version()` because I'm not adding the cache hash in development.

I currently have this in my `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.copyDirectory("src/assets/images", "public/images");
mix.setPublicPath("public");
if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version(["public/images"]); 
} else {
  // add images to manifest here...
}
```

I guess worst case scenario would be to read all image file names, and then write to the manifest manually, but I'd rather not go down that road if there's a simpler way.

Comment: In my codebase when I use mix.copy() on a particular file then it is added to mix manifest file even if I don't run mix.version().